# Dynamic cast to generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, type-conversion, castle-dynamicproxy

Just a quickie before the weekend rolls in...

I have a Method with the following signature, that I need to invoke:

```
public interface IObjectProvider<T>
{
    T Get(Predicate<T> condition);
}
```

This will provide me with a `T` from whatever kind of source, that meets the predicate criteria.

Now, this has to be called from a context where all I have is the following:

```
//the actual predicate that's going to be evaluated
var predicate = predicateProperty.GetValue(invocation.InvocationTarget, null);

//The type that should go into the call as type param
Type relationTargetType = relationDefinition.RelatedType;
```

As you might guess, the compiler won't let me use the `predicate` variable as parameter. What I need to do is convert this object into a Predicate, but Generic type params must be compile-time-constant, so this won't work.

I've started messing around with this, but no success so far:

```
Type genericPredicateType = typeof(Predicate<>);
Type specificPredicateType= genericPredicateType.MakeGenericType(relationTargetType);
Convert.ChangeType(predicate, specificPredicateType)
```

How on earth can I mash this up?

**EDIT:** I thought this was a rather use-case-agnostic question, but obviously I was wrong. So, since there is such a fuss as to what I do, what I have and why and whatnot, here's a lot more background info. I am trying to resolve relations between objects in a Proxy (Castle Dynamic Proxy). The following Snippet should explain the kind of relation I want to depict:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } // OR-Mapped
    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } // OR-Mapped

    [RelatedObject(typeof(Address), "DeliveryAddressPredicate")]
    public virtual Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

    public Predicate<Address> DeliveryAddressPredicate
    {
        get { return new Predicate<Address>(a => OrderDate >= a.ValidFrom && OrderDate <= a.ValidTo); }
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; } // OR-Mapped
    public virtual DateTime ValidTo { get; set; } // OR-Mapped

    //Not OR-Mapped
    [RelatedList(typeof(Order), "OrdersPredicate")]
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public Predicate<Order> OrdersPredicate
    {
        get { return new Predicate<Order>(o => o.OrderDate >= ValidFrom && o.OrderDate <= ValidTo); }
    }
```

To sum it up, this is supposed to become a Fuzzy OR-Mapping, meant to extend NHibernate in a project or two.

How did I mean to get this to work? The address is proxied, and when a call to a property with one of my CustomAttributes is made, i use DynamicProxy's IInterceptor interface to resolve the relation. The main problem is that this resolving has to happen in the IInterceptor.Intercept() Method which has only one Param ([see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9055/Castle-s-DynamicProxy-for-NET)), and I have no generic type param available. So, in the end it all boils down to a simple .Net question again: I have a `Type` stored in a variable and a `Method` that has to be called with a parameter generic of the aforesaid type...

Sorry for any mistakes made (like calling `var` a `Type` - man that was a rough one), it's been quite a day ;-)

Comment: What is the return type of `predicateProperty.GetValue`?

Comment: PropertyInfo.GetValue --> Object :-(

Comment: What is the type that is actually returned inside of that object?  `Predicate<Something>`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is...

Comment: Just an aside, but predicate is not of type `var`; `var` is not a type!

Comment: Yuck, reflection plus generics get really nasty, really quick.

Comment: @Eric, meh, it can be used judiciously.  Using `MakeGenericType` is not ipso facto "really nasty" code, yet it is by definition a convergence of generics and reflection.

Comment: @KirkWoll - I agree. Mostly just sympathizing with OP. It turns your brain in knots trying to figure out how to deal with it all.

Comment: reflection will give you a hard time. And if you haven't explicitely declared somewhere the generic types for all Ts, the compiled generic types won't even exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have some `IObjectProvider<T>`. If `T` is a type know at compile-time, you can just use a cast. For example, if `T` was `Foo`:

```
IObjectProvider<Foo> provider = …;
var predicate = (Predicate<Foo>)predicateProperty.GetValue(
    invocation.InvocationTarget, null);
Foo item = provider.Get(predicate);
```

**EDIT:** It seems you don't know `T` at compile time. This means you have two options:

1. Use `dynamic`:

   ```
   object provider = …
   object predicate = predicateProperty.GetValue(
       invocation.InvocationTarget, null);
   object item = ((dynamic)provider).Get((dynamic)predicate);
   ```
2. Use reflection:

   ```
   object provider = …;
   object predicate = predicateProperty.GetValue(
       invocation.InvocationTarget, null);
   var getMethod = provider.GetType().GetMethod("Get");
   object item = getMethod.Invoke(provider, new[] { predicate });
   ```

Comment: Please re-check the Original Post. I have no Compile-Time support here.

Comment: Thanks, Svick, this is the best answer I got, and I'm using the dynamic solution right now.

Comment: As mentioned above, I tried to get it to work using your dynamic sample, but I keep on running into ´CS1502 : The best overloaded method match for ... has some invalid arguments.´ Obviously the dynamic Type is not correctly resolved as being the static one defined in the ´Provider´-class. Any ideas how this can Occur?

Comment: You mean you get a compile error? Do you have some more details on the error? Which line is causing it? Is there some other message (something like “Argument 1: cannot convert from …”)?

Comment: object item = ((dynamic)provider).Get(predicate);

Comment: It occurs at runtime, not compile time. I guess that's what happens when you use dynamic...

Comment: You're right, the code doesn't work. But `((dynamic)provider).Get((dynamic)predicate)` does.

Answer (score 1):

This question shows a lot of confusion about types, var etc.

This is a meaningless sentence

> It is of type var and GetValue turned it into an object.

I think you are saying

> I have some code that needs a `Predicate<T>`

You have some code (that you don't show us) that returns an `Object`. And want somehow to coerce that return value into a `Predicate<T>`. If the returned object is a `Predicate<T>` then simply go `(Predicate<T>)retobj` - and you are done. If it's not a type that can be cast to `Predicate<T>` then no amount of jiggling will make it into a `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: The OP did show us that code: `predicateProperty.GetValue()`. Also, casting to `Predicate<T>` could work only inside a generic type or method with type parameter called `T`. Otherwise, you need to specify some concrete type, e.g. `(Predicate<string>)retobj`.

Comment: Also, you're slightly wrong that you can't make some other type into a `Predicate<T>`. For example, you can't cast `Func<string, bool>` to `Predicate<T>`, but you can use “jiggling” in the form of an constructor to do it: `new Predicate<string>(func)`.

Comment: Thanks, svick, for getting this straight. I will update the original Post to clarify the problem.

Comment: pm100, you actually got it boiled down to it's essence. I cannot cast the object to Predicate<T> (although it is one), since I have no Generic Type Parameter T. All I have is a variable that contains the type.

Answer (score -1):

I do this way

```
public T CastToType<T>(object objType, T type) where T : class
    {
        var cast = objType as T;

        if(cast == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException();

        return cast;
    }
```

And like this

```
var test = CastToType(objType, new ArrayList());
```

test will be have ArrayList type

Comment: Second argument not needed.