# Class name as string in defining a collection in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have class name as string that I got using TYPE

```
Type type = myvar.GetType();  
string _className = type.ToString(); // getting the class name
```

My question is how to use this string _className here in the code below?

```
var data = this.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<**_className**>()[2];
```

Here ItemsSource is generic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842222/dynamic-cast-to-generic-type

Comment: Instead of using the `string`, you can use the value of `type` along with some reflection to create an instance of a generic type. You can't use either of those directly in code though (that is, you can't write code of the form `ObservableCollection<xxx>` where the `xxx` is a variable).

Comment: Could try with `Type.GetType(_className)` to fetch the type.

Comment: Try `var data = (this.ItemsSource as IList)[2]`. Then you don't need to know the type

Comment: I didn't try creating an instance of a generic type, I will do and let me check

Comment: (this.ItemsSource as IList)[2] works, thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using reflection and the [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Type type = myvar.GetType();  
string className = type.ToString(); 
Type genericType = Type.GetType(className);
Type observableCollectionType = typeof(ObservableCollection<>);
Type constructedType = observableCollectionType.MakeGenericType(genericType);
var constructedInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType);
```