# Converting explicit type to T in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to make a generic type for retrieving data from API, however I can't cast explicit type to T in Get method:

Classes are arranged as follows:
PClass, MClass and SClass doesn't inherit over common parent (in fact they are just data model classes)

```
VMClass <- PagedResponse<T>, where T can be P-, M- or SClass
```

API sends very similar responses for all 3 Gets:
common `string name`, etc, and P-, M- or `SClass result[]`

I have few extension methods for casting explicit types:

```cs
internal static List<VMClass> ToVMElement(this List<MClass> ms) { ... }
internal static List<VMClass> ToVMElement(this List<pClass> ps) { ... }
internal static List<VMClass> ToVMElement(this List<sClass> ss) { ... }
```

When I'm trying to use switch-case for deciding which operation I want to perform, I'm returning explicit type of `PagedResponse<SClass>` (or `P-` `M-`) – experiencing [CS0029 – Cannot implicitly convert classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0029))

```cs
public static async Task<PagedResponse<T>> RetrieveApiData<T>(...)
{
    switch (typeof(T))
    {
        case Type m when m == typeof(MClass):
            PagedResponse<T> r = await GetMClasses(...);  // await returns PagedResponse<MClass>
            return r;
        case Type S when s == typeof(SClass):
            //...
    }
    //...
}
```

I understand that generic types are resolved at compilation, but I don't know how to accomplish that casting.

Comment: Have you considered using `dynamic` type, and checking `if (data is PClass\MClass\SClass)`?

Comment: I didn't even consider it, afaik `dynamic` casting is not a good practice, if it's not the only way to acomplish task, I would rather not use it. If I'm wrong, please correct me

Comment: When using `dynamic`, you don't have to cast the data, after checking `if (data is PClass)` you can use `data.MethodInPClass();` (You had to perform casting if you used `object` instead of `dynamic`)

Comment: Like in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/9842624/14345698 ?

Comment: Yes, you can try doing something like that.

Comment: Sorry for leaving topic for so long, I encountered some compile time issues. Anyway I used `dynamic` as you suggested, so far I have control over code flow, so risking some runtime issues for now is not a case. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a small set of known classes, then generics is most likely the wrong solution. You would most likely be better of just specifying the type in the method name

```
Task<PagedResponse<MClass>> RetrieveApiMClas(...)
Task<PagedResponse<pClass>> RetrieveApipClass(...)
Task<PagedResponse<sClass>> RetrieveApisClass(...)
```

This should not be more code than using generics with a switch, and it removes the possibility of runtime errors.

If you do not know what type an API call will return you might be able to use a [discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). Something like a `OneOf<MClass, pClass, sClass>`. That way the caller can handle each type in different ways. There is apparently a [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113) open to include this in the language, but it was not included in c# 11.

Comment: Actually I plan to use more endpoints, which will make use of about 20-30 classes, those are just my first approach.

Comment: @ikarmus so? I do not see any reason why `RetrieveApiData<MClass>` is preferable to `RetrieveApiDataMClass`, not if you need type specific code inside the generic method. I'm not really sure what the actual problem is, but if you need to do type checks in a generic method, there is a good chance you should be using some other pattern.

Comment: That's a fair point, I need to rethink my approach. Thanks for your help